How to Connect to PostgreSQL Server on Neon/Aiven/Supabase Using Prisma for nodejs?
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `aws-0-ap-south-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543`

Please make sure your database server is running at `aws-0-ap-south-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543`

I am working on a Node.js project and attempting to connect to a PostgreSQL database hosted on Neon/Aiven/Supabase using Prisma. I've verified that my environment variables are loading correctly, and the database URL seems to be accurate.
.env
DATABASE_URL="DATABASE_URL=postgresql://dummy_user:dummy_password@ep-dummy-url.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech/dummydb?sslmode=require
"

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

Then ran
npx prisma migrate dev --name init

But this gives the error

I also got that error and it was fixed by changing to port 5432.
